# What does this "none" do in .get() in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python through Learn Python the Hard Way. I'm now on Exercise 39 and have a simple question. I tried to search online but couldn't find any answers. Here's the code from the exercise:

```
# create a mapping of state to abbreviation
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}

# create a basic set of states and some cities in them
cities = {
    'CA': 'San Francisco',
    'MI': 'Detroit',
    'FL': 'Jacksonville'
}

print '-' * 10
# safely get a abbreviation by state that might not be there
state = states.get('Texas', None)

if not state:
    print "Sorry, no Texas."

# get a city with a default value
city = cities.get('TX', 'Does Not Exist')
print "The city for the state 'TX' is: %s" % city
```

I don't quite understand what `None` does in `state = states.get('Texas', None)`. If it were used to tell Python that "there is no more," then why couldn't I just write `state = states.get('Texas')`? What do I need the extra `None` here? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the whole reason to use `states.get('Texas')` instead of just `states['Texas']` is so you don't have to write code that explicitly deals with the "no Texas" case. When you're going to write that code, you should just use the brackets: `try:\n  state = states.get['Texas']\nexcept KeyError:\n  print "Sorry, no Texas."` I realize this is someone else's code that you're trying to understand, but… they've made it a little more difficult for you by being non-pythonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `None` here is a default value for [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) telling python what to return if the key does not exist. It is a little superfluous in this case, as `get()` defaults to `None` for the second parameter.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> get(key[, default])
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. 
>    If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this
>    method never raises a KeyError.

So it directly equivalent to `states.get('Texas')` which is equivalent to:

```
try:
    state = states['Texas']
except KeyError:
    state = None
```

So in this case, where you are then simply checking if `state` doesn't evaluate to `True`, it's pointless, it'd be better to simply do the try/except and perform the action you want on the exception (unless for some reason you are getting back other values you are also filtering out, such as empty strings, which seems unlikely).

The Python docs are detailed but clear, so in situations where you don't know what an argument is, check the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write the `None`, that is the default return value if the key was not found in the dictionary.  It is superfluous in this case.

You can replace it to return something else like `Not found` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `None` takes extra memory for the instruction `LOAD_CONST`.

```
Python 3.11.0a7 (main, Apr  5 2022, 21:27:39) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> a = {}
>>> dis.dis("a.get(2)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (get)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("a.get(2, None)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (get)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 CALL_METHOD              2
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```